# How to debug broken HTTP requests in Protractor?

Tags: angular, protractor

Here is a test in Protractor:

```
// Page object

import { $, browser, by, element } from 'protractor';

export class MediaPage {

  goTo(route: string) {
    browser.get(route);
    browser.wait(browser.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element(by.css('app-image-container'))), 10000);
  }

  getImageBlocks() {
    return element.all(by.css('app-image-container'));
  }
}

// Test

import { browser } from 'protractor';
import { MediaPage } from './app.po';

describe('Media page', () => {

  let page: MediaPage;

  beforeEach(() => {
    page = new MediaPage();
  });

  it ('should display list of images', () => {
    page.goTo('/media');
    //expect(page.getImageBlocks().count()).toEqual(20);
  });
});
```

Also, I have corporate proxy and these settings in protractor.config:

```
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    proxy: {
       proxyType: 'manual',
       httpProxy: 'http://proxy.xxxxx.com:80',
       sslProxy: 'http://proxy.xxxxx.com:80'
    },
    chromeOptions: {
        //binary: 'F:/Program/GoogleChromePortable/App/Chrome-bin/chrome.exe',
        args: ['--test-type', '--no-proxy-server', '--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs'],
        extensions: []
    }
```

When I open page in browser it should load data from the API using HTTP request. Appp works under localhost:4200, API allows cross origin requests. Application works fine but test hangs for 10 seconds while it's waiting for page to be loaded and then dies. I can't open Dev Console in Chrome because test stops, I can't use console.log() because console is invisible.

**Question:** How can I find out what happened to HTTP request and why it's not loading data?

**Update:** I just realized that it's probably because it can't send request when proxy is disabled, but the question is the same, how can I see (debug) HTTP request in Protractor if I don't have access to Dev Tools. In addition, when I try to start Chrome with proxy enabled then loading of my app is intercepted by corporate Firewall, ZScaler, and page is blocked as insecure. Is it possible to force Chrome to not send information about local pages (localhost:4200) to the Firewall?

Comment: If you are looking for a way to capture the console logs, then https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/logging/performance-log this will help.

Answer (score 0):

For how to see the HTTP request, I suggest you install a traffic monitor tool like the well known [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) and set Chrome to use the Fiddler proxy (usually http://127.0.0.1:8888 but you may change the port in the Fiddler settings)
It has saved me huge amount of time